# Height of canvas needed to change with responsive text of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a responsive canvas which draws a text. The size of canvas needs to change when the size of browser is altered. The font size also changes with change in browser size which requires the height of canvas to be altered. Currently I have given it fixed height. I can't assign height after font is set. For some reason, font size gets affected as well.

PS. please ignore classes used in various divs. They are there because for css frameworks present.

html

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="canvasdiv">
    <canvas id="quesCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var htmlCanvas = document.getElementById('quesCanvas'),
            context = htmlCanvas.getContext('2d'),
            fontBase = 1000,
            fontSize = 22;
        var text="<?php echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dolor nunc, accumsan a blandit eu, malesuada ac justo. Sed vel nibh tempor, pretium felis id, tempor elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum quis vestibulum sem. Quisque ullamcorper velit et ultrices blandit. Aenean turpis mauris, tincidunt vel interdum semper, interdum in odio. Ut venenatis, turpis non vestibulum porta, ligula nisi scelerisque massa, eget vulputate urna urna non mauris. Integer faucibus lacinia purus sit amet tempor. Aenean in orci vel justo condimentum faucibus. Integer congue eleifend ipsum volutpat aliquam. Vivamus varius dui at dolor lacinia, at luctus metus vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent rutrum leo quis mi porttitor, at euismod magna sollicitudin. Nam aliquam sodales libero, id vulputate nulla tempus ac." ?>";
        var words=text.split(' ');
        initialize();

        function initialize() {
            window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
            resizeCanvas();
        }

        function redraw() {
            context.font=getFont();
            context.fillStyle="#000";
            var line = '';
            var x=0, y=40, lineHeight=30, maxWidth = htmlCanvas.width;
            for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
                var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
                var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
                var testWidth = metrics.width;
                if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
                    context.fillText(line, x, y);
                    line = words[n] + ' ';
                    y += lineHeight;
                }
                else {
                    line = testLine;
                }
            }
            context.fillText(line, x, y);
        }

        function resizeCanvas() {
            htmlCanvas.height = 500;
            htmlCanvas.width = $("#canvasdiv").width();
            redraw();
        }

        function getFont() {
            var ratio = fontSize / fontBase;
            var size = htmlCanvas.width * ratio;
            if (size<10) size = 10;

            return (size|0) + 'px sans-serif';
        }

    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you bit or-ing the return value in getFont?

Comment: it floors the size... 2.3456 is floored to 2 ...